# Can I define two exact same commands using /newcommand with the only difference is one is lower case and the other is upper case

Tags: macros, overleaf, renewcommand, uppercase

In my macro file, I have defined two commands

```
\newcommand{\SO}[1]{\mathsf{SO}(#1)}
\newcommand{\so}[1]{\mathfrak{so}(#1)}
```

There are two exact same commands with the only difference is in case. When I use it in my main file, I get the following error:

**LaTeX Error: Command \so already defined**

The worrying part is, this was working before but now it has stopped working. Am I missing some package or something? If I do, what package would it be?

Thanks!

Comment: Yes, you can. But not if one of them is already defined by something else (a package or a class). It looks like you maybe added a package to your document that does define `\so`.

Comment: `\so` is defined in the `soul` package. Do you use it? And `\so`, `\SO`, `\So` and `\sO` are **four different** commands, so you have other possibilities.

Comment: Yes, the soul package was added in my document but I was not using it. So commenting it out works for me. Thanks a lot! :)